# Unable to set cookies

Tags: javascript, express, cookies

Having major issues with this. I spent a great deal of time today trying to get cookies to work on the client side. I am unsure what I am doing wrong seeing as I can see the cookie in the response header after signing up.

I have used cookie-parser, document.cookie. res.set('Set-Cookie') and none of them work. What am I missing?

```
app.post('/signUp', function(req, res) {
 var username = req.body.username;
 var password = req.body.password;

 db.collection('users').find({username: username})
 .then((user) => {
   console.log(user);
   if(user[0]){
    console.log('bad request');
     res.status(400).end("bad request");
     res.set("Connection", "close");
   } else {
     return Utils.hashPassword(password)
   }
 })
 .then(function(hash){
  console.log('Running hash promise')
   return db.collection('users').insert({username: username, password: hash});
 })
 .then(function(obj){
   console.log("Data returned from inserting:", obj);
   var sessionId = Utils.createSessionId();
   console.log("Line 44:", sessionId);
   return db.collection('sessions').insert({id: obj._id, sessionId: sessionId});
 })
 .then(function(obj){
  console.log("Data returned from inserting into sessions:", obj)
   res.cookie("session_id", obj.sessionId, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false})
   res.send("yay!");
 })
})
```

Comment: You asked about why it isn't working on the client side, but you only showed us your server-side code. Can we see your client side code?

Comment: Client side is just a couple input fields, button, and divs set up as a test page using React. Looking at the Resources->Cookies tab nothing appears after signing up
Is there something I should be doing on the client side to set the cookie?

Comment: Check the domain/path of your cookie. Use the cookies list in the setting to see if it is saved under a subdomain. Also the docs mention that max age is a string option.

Comment: upvote for setting the path on the cookie, that tripped me up once